# Building a class for matrices

Tags: luatex, lua

The following code may have many problems, but it compiles.
I want to build a (pseudo)class to introduce metamethods (+,-,*), but first I have a little problem that I haven't encountered with the other classes in my package. To be able to use matrix A, I'm obliged by my code (I've borrowed a few parts left and right) to write `A.tbl` to manipulate it.
Is it possible to modify my code to use `A` and not `A.tbl`?
Remark: chatGPT hates my code and is probably right!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{tkz-elements}
\begin{document}
\LuaCodeDebugOn 

\begin{luacode}
matrix={}
function matrix: new (value)
    local type          = 'matrix'
    local rows          = #value
    local cols          = #value[1]
    local tbl           = value
    local o =  {tbl     = tbl,
                rows    = rows,
                cols    = cols,
                type    = type }
    setmetatable(o, self)
    self.__index = self
    return o
end
return matrix 
\end{luacode}

\begin{luacode}
function print_matrix(matrix)
tex.print("\\{%")
  for i = 1, #matrix do
    local row = matrix[i]
    local row_str = "{\\{"
    for j = 1, #row do
        row_str = row_str .. " " .. tostring(row[j])
        if j < #row then
            row_str = row_str .. ","
        end
    end
    row_str = row_str .. "\\}}"
    tex.sprint(row_str)
  end
tex.print("\\}")
end

function product_matrix(A, B)
  local C = {}
  for i = 1, #A do
      C[i] = {}
      for j = 1, #B[1] do
          local num = A[i][1] * B[1][j]
          for k = 2, #A[1] do
              num = num + A[i][k] * B[k][j]
          end
          C[i][j] = num
      end
  end
  return C
end
\end{luacode}
  
\begin{tkzelements}
a = point(1,0)
b = point(0,1)
c = point(1,1)
d = point(1,-1)
A = matrix : new ({{1, 2}, {1,3}})
B = matrix : new ({{2, 3}, {-5, 4}})
Z = {{a, b}, {c,d}}
Z = product_matrix(Z,Z)
W = product_matrix(A.tbl,Z)
\end{tkzelements}

\parindent=0pt
\verb|A = matrix : new ({{1, 2}, {1,3}})|

Matrix A:\directlua{print_matrix(A.tbl)}

\verb|Z = {{a, b}, {c,d}}|

Matrix Z*Z:\directlua{print_matrix(Z)}

Matrix W=A*Z:\directlua{print_matrix(W)}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

You can if you wish accept either the outer class or the inner `tbl` data, checking at run time the argument types, so you can pass in `A` or `A.tbl`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage{tkz-elements}
\begin{document}
\LuaCodeDebugOn 

\begin{luacode}
matrix={}
function matrix: new (value)
    local type          = 'matrix'
    local rows          = #value
    local cols          = #value[1]
    local tbl           = value
    local o =  {tbl     = tbl,
                rows    = rows,
                cols    = cols,
                type    = type }
    setmetatable(o, self)
    self.__index = self
    return o
end
return matrix 
\end{luacode}

\begin{luacode}
function print_matrix(matrix)
local mdata = (matrix.type=='matrix' and matrix.tbl or matrix)
tex.print("\\{%")
  for i = 1, #mdata do
    local row = mdata[i]
    local row_str = "{\\{"
    for j = 1, #row do
        row_str = row_str .. " " .. tostring(row[j])
        if j < #row then
            row_str = row_str .. ","
        end
    end
    row_str = row_str .. "\\}}"
    tex.sprint(row_str)
  end
tex.print("\\}")
end

function product_matrix(A, B)
local adata = (A.type=='matrix' and A.tbl or A)
local bdata = (B.type=='matrix' and B.tbl or B)
local C = {}
  for i = 1, #adata do
      C[i] = {}
      for j = 1, #bdata[1] do
          local num = adata[i][1] * bdata[1][j]
          for k = 2, #adata[1] do
              num = num + adata[i][k] * bdata[k][j]
          end
          C[i][j] = num
      end
  end
  return C
end
\end{luacode}
  
\begin{tkzelements}
a = point(1,0)
b = point(0,1)
c = point(1,1)
d = point(1,-1)
A = matrix : new ({{1, 2}, {1,3}})
B = matrix : new ({{2, 3}, {-5, 4}})
Z = {{a, b}, {c,d}}
Z = product_matrix(Z,Z)
W = product_matrix(A.tbl,Z)
WW = product_matrix(A,Z)
\end{tkzelements}

\parindent=0pt
\verb|A = matrix : new ({{1, 2}, {1,3}})|

Matrix A:\directlua{print_matrix(A)}

Matrix A (tbl):\directlua{print_matrix(A.tbl)}

\verb|Z = {{a, b}, {c,d}}|

Matrix Z*Z:\directlua{print_matrix(Z)}

Matrix tbl W=A*Z:\directlua{print_matrix(WW)}

Matrix W=A*Z:\directlua{print_matrix(W)}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks David, This is indeed a solution, but is it possible to consider another solution, such as modifying the `function matrix: new (value)` ? What I'd like is to no longer have to use `.tbl`. I don't know Lua well enough, but I had the impression that the correct use of `setmetatable` could solve my problem.

Comment: @AlainMatthes I may look later, also your functions seemed a bit odd. You only need to switch between A and A.tbl versions as your functions take the first form but just return the raw data form not a table of the type you define. if your matrix product returned a table with type=matrix rather than simply the raw table data you would only have to deal with those tables and the .tbl would be an internal field you'd never see

Comment: Sorry my question was badly formulated and confusing. Finally, with your answer, it's enough to replace `return C` with ` return matrix : new (C)`.

Comment: Thanks again, I've been able to introduce a metamethod: the first function matrix.__mul(m1,m2)!